# Relationship between Uniform Law of Large Numbers and Glivenko-Cantelli

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

The Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem) states that for $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ with common c.d.f. $F$, $$\|F_n-F\|_\infty = \sup|F_n(x)-F(x)|\stackrel{a.s.}{\to}0,$$
where $F_n$ is the empirical c.d.f. for a sample size $n$.

Slide 2 of [Bartlett's lecture notes](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/2013spring-stat210b/notes/8notes.pdf) state that this theorem is an *example* of a uniform law of large numbers (ULLN). This implies that there are other ULLNs. Is this understanding correct?

Additionally, slide 5 in the same notes states that the Glivenk-Cantelli Theorem is a special case of the Glivenko-Cantelli class. Is the Glivenko-Cantelli class a broader ULLN than the theorem? Obviously, a set of functions which is a GC class follows ULLN. Does following ULLN also imply that a function is a GC class?